# Will tar -cvzf packed.tar.gz mydir take hidden files into account?

Tags: directory, tar, gzip

I need to create a tarball of a given directory. However, I need to make sure hidden files are included too (such as those beginning with `.`).

Will the following command automatically take the hidden files into account?

```
tar -cvzf packed.tar.gz mydir
```

If not, how can I make sure I include hidden files?

Comment: use `tar -cvzf packed.tar.gz mydir/.`

Comment: NOTICE: In my case, I've realized(by experiment) that `tar czvf something.tar.gz path` contains them, but `tar czvf something.tar.gz path/*` doesn't!

Comment: @aderchox Yes because the file glob will not expand dot files.

Comment: For those who would like to archive all items in the current directory, the following worked for me: `$ tar czvf ../archive.tar.gz .` Whereas if the trailing dot is replaced by a `*` then the (hidden, in some sense) dotfiles from the current directory are not included.

Comment: by default, "hidden files" when the file name starts with "." are included in tar operation. If you don't want "hidden files" to include in tar, then use `--exclude=".*"` explicitly.

Comment: Easy enough to just test, isn't it?  `mkdir mydir/; date > mydir/.hidden1; touch mydir/.hidden2; date > mydir/not-hidden; tar -cvzf packed.tar.gz mydir/; tar xvf packed.tar.gz` should tell all.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes, it will.

Files starting with `.` are not "hidden" in all contexts.  They aren't expanded by `*`, and `ls` doesn't list them by default, but `tar` doesn't care about the leading `.`.  (`find` doesn't care either.)

(Of course, this is one of those things that's easy to find out by experiment.)

Comment: Thanks. Yes experiment is sometimes a solution to find an answer, but in this case, I am not a unix expert and I know behaviors - in general - can be modified with configuration. What if two systems are not configured the same way? The belief I might build from one system might not be true for another.

Comment: @JVerstry: Good point. A suggestion, though; a question like "I tried this, and it worked; is it guaranteed?" would have been even better.

Comment: `tar --help` lists several different options, all beginning with `--exclude` that allow one to exclude various files based on name, pattern, etc. Agreed, experimentation is a great way to test and verify if something works as expected. Make backups regularly!

Comment: FWIW, this didn't work for me - no hidden files were included in my tar.gz.

Comment: @zigojacko That's very surprising. Can you show the exact command you used? If you used a `*` wildcard in the `tar` command, it was expanded by the shell, not by `tar`.

Comment: @RiccardoManfrin There was no `*` in the question. If you do `tar cvzf data.tar.gz *`, the `*` is expanded by the shell; `tar` never sees it. If you do `tar cvzf data.tar.gz '*'`, `tar` will see the `*` and will interpret as a file literally named `*`. `tar` (at least GNU `tar`) does have some support for wildcards, but as far as I know only for files in an archive. https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/wildcards.html

Comment: @KeithThompson agreed. but the first sentence was confusing to me: prefixing with the "." commonly stands for hidden files. Besides this being or not the use case for ".",  I would emphasize that using the "*" is interpeted by any unix command as "all files but not the ones starting with a dot" and that tar is no exception

Comment: @RiccardoManfrin As far as the file system is concerned, `.` is just another character. In some limited contexts (`ls`, the shell's `*` wildcard, and some commands that have wildcard features similar to the shell), files with names starting with `.` are hidden. But it's very important to remember that wildcard expansion is performed *by the shell*. `tar` is no exception because it can't be; it never sees the wildcard.